# Agular full calendar view events styling

Tags: css, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, angular-calendar

I want to Add hover effects on Events of Angular Full-calendar-view(using this version ^5.10.2).
I tried by using eventMouseEnter and eventMouseLeave functions but it's not helping me to add effects on events.
Pic attached to show events on Full calendar.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb2fG.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: HTML:<div class="card-body p-0">
        <full-calendar  [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
      </div>

TS:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agular full calendar view events styling(hover effect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72612897/agular-full-calendar-view-events-stylinghover-effect)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you use Jquery, but if yes, you could define your hover style(s) in a class (in my case, `.event_hover`) and then do something like...

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
    var $el = $(info.el);        
    $el.hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("event_hover");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("event_hover");
    });
}
```

If you don't use jQuery, you may could do something similar in Javascript, but at the end the key is to modify the eventDidMount event.
Hope it goes right for you.