# Agular full calendar view events styling(hover effect)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, angular-calendar

I want to Add hover effects on Events of Angular Full-calendar-view(using this version ^5.10.2).
I tried by using eventMouseEnter and eventMouseLeave functions but it's not helping me to add effects on events.
Pic attached to show events on Full calendar.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb2fG.png)

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
        <full-calendar  [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
      </div>
```

TS:

```
export class FullcalendarviewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService,private taskservice:TasksService,public datepipe: DatePipe,public _router:Router) {   }
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.getTaskList();
  }
 
  getTaskList(){
    this.taskservice.getallTaskCalendar().subscribe(data =>{
      this.tasklist=data.Data[1];
      console.log('Task API data of full calendar',this.tasklist);
      this.tasklist = this.tasklist.map((e: any) => ({ Id:e.TaskId,title: e.TaskName, start: e.TaskDueDate,end:this.datepipe.transform(e.TaskDueDate , 'YYYY-MM-dd')+"T24:00:00" ,description:e.TaskDetails,For:e.AccountName,Type:e.TaskType, allDay: true }));
      this.calendarOptions = {
         eventMouseEnter:this.handleEventMouseEnter.bind(this),
         eventMouseLeave:this.handleEventMouseLeave.bind(this),
       eventClick:this.Eventfunc.bind(this),  
        events:this.tasklist,    
      };
    });
  eventType:any;
  handleDateClick(arg) {  
 this.modalService.show(CalendarAddTaskModalComponent);
  }
  handleEventMouseEnter(){
console.log('Mouse entered');
  }
  handleEventMouseLeave(){
    console.log('Mouse out'); 
  } 
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a repeated question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72603972/agular-full-calendar-view-events-styling. Please, edit the question whenever you want to add more information, but don't repeat it in a new one